# Search from List which is in ViewModel (Xamarin Android )

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross, searchview

I am new to Xamarin Android Development and I am using **MvvmCross** for binding data.I have **SerachView** on action-bar.I want to search data from list which is in ViewModel.How can I implement that ? I have searched for this issue on internet but all have used adapter and i want to search list-item without using adapter from ViewModel.I am not getting any idea how to do that.So anyone can suggest me an easy way?

Any suggestion or advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is pretty simple.

Your `SearchView` is bound to a string property which you are using for filtering. Here I assume it is called `SearchQuery`.

It is not clear what criteria you want to use for filtering, I will assume that the ViewModel has a `Name` property, where the `SearchQuery` will be contained in that name.

So your ViewModel would look something like:

```
public class SearchViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    public string SearchQuery
    {
        get { return _searchQuery; }
        set {
            _searchQuery = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => SearchQuery);
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => FilteredResults);
        }
    }

    public List<ListItemViewModel> UnfilteredResults 
    {
        get { return _unfilteredResults; }
        set {
            _unfilteredResults = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => UnfilteredResults);
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => FilteredResults);
        }
    }

    public List<ListItemViewModel> FilteredResults
    {
        get 
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchQuery)) 
                return UnfilteredResults;

            return UnfilteredResults
                .Where(r => r.Name.Contains(SearchQuery)).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

So what happens is, whenever you enter a new value into the search box, it will trigger the PropertyChanged event on `FilteredResults` and use a simple LINQ query to filter the results.

If you don't want to swap out the entire list every time, you can do this with an ObservableCollection and add and remove items in that instead.

**EDIT:**

So as stated above you just bind the `MvxListView` to the new items source. Assuming you are using a AXML layout for your view:

```
<MvxListView
  ..
  local:MvxBind="ItemsSource FilteredResults; ItemClick ResultClickedCommand" />
```

As for the `SearchView`, I just looked, there does not seem to be any code in MvvmCross to easily bind to that, and it does not inherit from `EditText`, so you need to do something like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22501906/368379

Easiest way is probably simply to implement the `SearchView.IOnQueryTextListener` interface and in there set the new string you receive in the implementation on your `ViewModel`.

Comment: Thanks.I will try this @cheesebaron

Comment: How to bind this SearchQuery to SearchView and how can I show that filtered list on view ? @Cheesebaron

Comment: How can I bind this Searchquery to Searchview in axml ?@Cheesebaron

Comment: Instead listview I want to show a dropdown list ? How to implement that ?

Comment: Create another question it is not related.